# Does it matter if a door is placed facing the opposite way when building villages?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building an artificial village for the purpose of a Iron Golem grinder and I am curious to know whether the direction the door faces on a "house" will affect the village behavior.

I am building the door in the direction opposite to normal village doors because I don't want villagers to be able to stand on the block below the door and escape the village.

I am wondering whether the game's programming allows a house with a door placed from the inside of a structure.

Comment: Umm... I don't really know what you're asking. Can you add some screenshots demonstrating what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Ben, A door doesn't take a full block, so depending on where you stand when you place it, a door can either be flush with the 'outside' wall (having the block-gap on the inside of the house), or flush with the inside wall.

Comment: I just changed some spelling, but you kind of left us hanging without finishing the statement at the last part of the question.

Comment: I have no time to read it now but it might help you figuring out: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Village_mechanics#Housing

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What constitutes a house for villagers?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52527/what-constitutes-a-house-for-villagers)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you make sure you place the door frontally at the entrance it doesn't matter whether you are placing from inside or outside of the house. If you place the door sideways in the entrance it might or might not be a valid door for the village, depending on the house design.

To make sure the door is places frontally rather than sideways, press F3 and look at the door - at the right side it says `open: true` or `open: false`. That is what the game 'thinks' about the state of the door. If the door looks closed when it reads `open: false` (and looks open when it reads `open: true`), the door is correctly placed.

Really it is easier to do right than to do it wrong, so if you place the doors naturally they will probably be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Place a door from two different directions. Seeing the difference, generally place doors from the outside of any structure you want to protect. The reason for this is that skeletons can't shoot into the side flush with a block, thus being more protected in your village house.

Comment: Realizing what you're trying to ask- it doesn't seem to matter, as long as the villagers have a "house" (via the game's programming) to enter. They will tend to stand inside at night, at least.

Comment: I was wondering weather the games programming allowed a house with a door placed from the inside

Comment: @popgalop no. If a structure (4 walls and a roof) has a wooden door, it counts as a valid structure for a villager. (Including breeding). the facing of the door is irrelevant. The only requirement is that it *has* to be a *wooden* door. Gates and Iron doors don't count

Answer (score -1):

it does not matter as long as its a wooden door, because of how it is progrmmed